# Subdirect products

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra, direct-product

My question actually regards to slightly degenerate case of a subdirect product:

Is every algebra a subdirect product of itself alone I.e. of the product only involving itself once?

Comment: In a trivial way, yes: $\mathbf A \cong \prod \{\mathbf A\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Burris and Sankappanavar, Ch. II.

> **Definition 8.1.**
>   An algebra $\mathbf A$ is a *subdirect product* of an indexed family $(\mathbf A_i)_{i \in I}$ of algebras if
>    (i) $\mathbf A \leq \prod_{i \in I} \mathbf A_i$
>    (ii) $\pi_i(\mathbf A) = \mathbf A_i$, for each $i \in I$.

(Here, $\pi_i$ is the i-th projection, 
$\pi_j: \prod_{i\in I} \mathbf A_i \to \mathbf A_j$ defined by $\pi_j(a) = a(j)$.)

Now if $\mathbf A = \prod_{i \in I} \mathbf A_i$, then $\pi_i(\mathbf A) = \mathbf A_i$, by definition of the projections.
So a direct product is always a subdirect product.
In particular, you can take $I = \{1\}$ and $\mathbf A_1 = \mathbf A$, and conclude that $\mathbf A$ is a subdirect product of itself.

Comment: is this the same as subalgebra of a direct product ?

Comment: It's not *any* subalgebra of the direct product. Note that by (i) in the definition, it is a subalgebra of the direct product, but then it must also satisfy (ii).

Comment: Would the statement stillt hold for the case of being any subalgebra of a direct product, in this specific case? @amrsa

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking if any subalgebra of the direct product is a subdirect product? If that's your question, then the answer is no (see the definition). If not, please clarify.

Comment: My refinement was about my original question, whether every algebra can be expressed as a subalgebra of a direct product of itself, not specifically a subdirect product, i.e. does your answer YES hold in the case of sudirect being replaced by the other notion.

Comment: @N.Wolf Yes. I'm sorry if the answer was not clear enough. Every algebra is a direct product of itself (with one single factor). Moreover, every algebra is a subalgebra of itself; thus, a subalgebra of a direct product of itself. Since every direct product is subdirect, then every algebra is a subdirect product of itself. I suppose this is what you were asking.